# Import data from sql server to spark local

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to import a table from sql server to spark local using JDBC driver and run spark sql on top of it.  I downloaded sqljdbc for sql server and added this line to the *spark-env.sh* in the conf directory:

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH= "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar" ./bin/spark-shell
```

As suggested by [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)

And use this line to load the data

```
df = sqlContext.load(source="jdbc", url="jdbc:sqlserver:dd", dbtable="Reporting.dbo.datatable")
```

However, it throws an error as:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:PC-BFS2
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(JDBCRelation.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

So earlier versions of Spark might have this issue if it isn't also set on the driver class path, so you can try adding the jar to the driver class path as well (which can be specified with `--driver-class-path`).. I'm not super familiar with deploying on Windows systems, but you might also wish to set you properties in `conf/spark-env.cmd` as suggested in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html .

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath        "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would be to pass the location of driver when doing spark-submit as below (it works well for me)

```
./bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar --master spark://ip:7077 mycode.py
```

Please make sure that you have the above location of sqljdbc added in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-default.conf and under property spark.jars